# How to Change Placeholder text of Zip code at Cart page in woocommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to know

How to Change Placeholder text of Zip code at Cart page,it changes when I click the zip code filed.

suppose before clicking the zip code fieled it is "POSTCODE" and when I click in zip code field ,placeholder text changes to "postcode" ,I want to have same placeholder whether clicked or not in zip code field

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Based from [Woocommerce Documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'my_override_checkout_fields' );
function my_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {   
    #Override Placeholder
    $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['placeholder'] = 'POSTALCODE';
    return $fields;
}
```